# Generate Time Segment Labels, Smallest Timespan to Increment DateTime Format

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan, datetime-format

I came up with what I thought was a good question: How do I get every label between two DateTimes for a specified Date Format.
Wondered if anyone had a more elegant solution than what I came up with.  (Other than knowing the format at compile time)  Or any ways to optimize this.

I'm using this to generate a graph where not all time segments have a value (so  `.GroupBy(date => date.ToString(dateFormat))` results in skipping any time period that has zero elements)

For example: Output every label between 2011/01/01 and 2011/03/21 with the date format "yyyyMM"
`GetTimeSegmentLables(new DateTime(2011,1,1), new DateTime(2011,3,21), "yyyyMM").Dump();`
This should also supports a format such as `"yyyy MM 'Month' dddd\\'\\s"`

This is What I came up with:

```
public static List<string> GetTimeSegmentLabels(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string dateFormat)
{
    DateTime incrementedDate = startDate;
    TimeSpan increment = GetSmallestUnitInDateFormat(dateFormat);

    int estimatedCount = (int)((endDate - startDate).TotalMilliseconds / increment.TotalMilliseconds + 1);
    List<string> Formats = new List<string>(estimatedCount);

    string LastFormat = "";
    while (incrementedDate < endDate)
    {
        string next = incrementedDate.ToString(dateFormat);
        if (next != LastFormat)
        {
            Formats.Add(next);
            LastFormat = next;
        }
        incrementedDate = incrementedDate.Add(increment);
    }
    if (LastFormat != endDate.ToString(dateFormat))
        Formats.Add(endDate.ToString(dateFormat));

    return Formats;
}

public static TimeSpan GetSmallestUnitInDateFormat(string dateFormat)
{
    //Remove escaped characters
    string stripped = Regex.Replace(dateFormat, "(\\\\.|'[^']+'|\"[^\"]+\")", "");

    //Check for format strings in increasing order
    if (stripped.Contains("F") || stripped.Contains("F"))
    {
        //TODO find longest [fF]+ string
    }
    if (stripped.Contains("s"))
    {
        return new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    }
    if (stripped.Contains("m"))
    {
        return new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
    }
    if (stripped.Contains("h") || stripped.Contains("H"))
    {
        return new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
    }
    if (stripped.Contains("d"))
    {
        return new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    if (stripped.Contains("M"))
    {
        //30 is the average month (365.25/12) but there is a chance it would skip Feburary...
        //So 28 should hit every month for each year, hitting one twice
        return new TimeSpan(28, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    if (stripped.Contains("y"))
    {
        return new TimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Unable to find any supported Format Specifier");
}
```

Comment: Consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for that

Comment: Ah, yes that would be a better place for this...  Was unaware of it